# JS form submit wont sent success message if mail sent or not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email

Hi all i am trying to send mails without having the page reload, form validation etc all seems to work ok but i cannot find out if mail is being sent or not as not success message is being printed

here is my html, js and php code

The html

```
<form name="ContactForm" method="post" action="">   
<div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;"></div>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name:" />
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email:" />
      <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone:" />
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message:" /></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default" value="Send message">
</form>
```

the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var delay = 2000;
       $('.btn-default').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   var name = $('#name').val();
       if(name == ''){
       $('.message_box').html(
       '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Name!</span>'
       );
       $('#name').focus();
       return false;
   }        
   var email = $('#email').val();
       if(email == ''){
       $('.message_box').html(
       '<span style="color:red;">Enter Email Address!</span>'
       );
       $('#email').focus();
       return false;
   }
   if( $("#email").val()!='' ){
       if( !isValidEmailAddress( $("#email").val() ) ){
           $('.message_box').html(
           '<span style="color:red;">Provided email address is incorrect!</span>'
           );
           $('#email').focus();
           return false;
       }
   }
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
       if(phone == ''){
       $('.message_box').html(
       '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Phone With Country Code!</span>'
       );
       $('#phone').focus();
       return false;
   }                    
   var message = $('#message').val();
       if(message == ''){
       $('.message_box').html(
       '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Message Here!</span>'
       );
       $('#message').focus();
          return false;
   }                        
   $.ajax
   ({
       type: "POST",
           url: "quickmail.php",
               data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&message="+message,
               beforeSend: function() {
               $('.message_box').html(
               '<img src="images/loading.gif" width="25" height="25"/>'
           );
           },        
           success: function(data)
           {
           setTimeout(function() {
               $('.message_box').html(data);
               }, delay);
           }
       });
    });         
});
```

And lastly the php code

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) !="" && isset($_POST['email']) !=""){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "email@yourdomain.com";
$subject = "New Query";
$message = "<p>New email is received from $name.</p>
<p>$message</p>";


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$email.">" . "\r\n";
$sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($sent){
    echo "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>
    Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.
    </span>";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Thanks $name, we have received your message.")</script>';
}else{
    echo "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>
    Sorry! Your form submission is failed.
    </span>";
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate it one of you pros could help me fix it.

Thanks a ton in advance

**UPDATE**

As suggested i tried json but still nothing is being printed?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');   
$json = json_encode($data);
if(isset($_POST['name']) !="" && isset($_POST['email']) !=""){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "email@yourdomain.com";
$subject = "New Query";
$message = "<p>New email is received from $name.</p>
<p>$message</p>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$email.">" . "\r\n";
$sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($sent){
    $data = "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>
    Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.
    </span>";
}else{
    $data = "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>
    Sorry! Your form submission is failed.
    </span>";
    }
}
echo $json;
```

Comment: Your php code was a "success" regardless of whether what it did (the email) was or not.  As you return HTML from an API call (never a good idea) your js doesn't know the difference (other than by parsing the HTML and looking for "failed", which is an even worse idea).   Instead, return json from the php with one property as a flag for sent yes/no and another property for the message to display (if you want it in php rather than js).

Comment: Not your issue but `if(isset($_POST['name']) !="" && isset($_POST['email']) !=""){` can just be `if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'])){`. Also should fix indentations.

Comment: @freedomn-m couuld you help me out please would really appreciate it

Comment: @user3783243 thanks that was indeed something i did know.

Comment: [tag:php] not my strong point, sorry - have a look for how to return json from php.   Simplest solution would be to change your response to `if($sent){echo "sent";}else{echo "failed";}` then check in your jquery for `success: function(data) { if (data === "sent") ...`

Comment: I did the part on PHP really confused how to check on my JQ code if sent has message

Comment: You should move `$json = json_encode($data);` to the bottom, right before you echo the `$json`variable (after you've defined it and given it a value). Right now you're encoding a non existing variable (since `$data` hasn't been defined yet). You can't use variables before they exist. It also doesn't make sense to just json encode a single string.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson appreciate it, i changed that part but now how do i make my js print the message inside my form if success of failed?

Comment: currently after the json my form loading.gif keeps loading on submit

Comment: `$data = ".."; echo $json;` that's not JSON, that's just a string variable named "json".  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php